# Can I use a hotspot without data to connect to a wifi speaker?

Tags: iphone, wifi, audio, tethering, speakers

I recently bought a WiFi speaker that needs to connect to a WiFi connection to play music from my phone.  I also travel out of the country a couple times a year but do not have a data plan for out of the USA.  Is there a way I can turn on my mobile hot-spot to connect my speaker to my phone without actually using data so I don't pay outrageous international data charges?  I currently have an iPhone 7.

Answer (score 1):

No. Your iPhone can only join or create a Wi-Fi network at any one time. It can't do both simultaneously.

But you can buy a small [travel router](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B00I00J8DW/) to do what you want. Both your speaker and iPhone would connect to it.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no way. A hotspot on iPhone can only be used with data. The speaker might check for new updates which will result in some bandwidth.

Is there no way to connect or via Bluetooth as that won’t use data. Most speakers should offer that nowadays.